# .rc files with preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, rc

I´m working on VS2015 with a C++ project containing only one `.rc` file. I would like to change the content of my `.rc` file with preprocessor directives. For example, `#define freeVersion`, set somewhere else in a header file.

But for some reasons, when I include the header file containing the define, I got errors like:

> rc1004 unexpected end of file found

Is there a way to fix this issue (read about it but found nothing)? Should I use multiple `.rc` files (`free.rc` / `nonFree.rc` for example)?

Comment: PP directives and include files etc all work in .rc files so it's hard to tell what your actual problem is: please show actual code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sound like you have a non-POSIX file created with no *newline* after the final text in the file. Some object compilers can be finicky. Make the change to add a newline, then open the *VS Developer's Command Prompt* and attempt to compile your resource file to object with `rc /Fonameoffile.res nameoffile.rc` and see if the error occurs again. (a single resource file is fine) The `/Fo` option just allows you to provide a name for the compiled resource object file you will like with your program.

Comment: The problem was a bad end of line character ... Thanks ;)